# Android Keyboard event is not capturing in case of Content Editable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I have created a custom js editor in react typescript using div which is not an input box. In case of android i am facing problem because to open a native android keyboard so i have to make the div contenteditable due to which if i type from the native android keyboard it is typing in the placeholder although it is working fine in case of ios. I had also tried onBeforeinput approach for getting the input from android keyboard but it is not working in all scenarios. Any solution for this ?

I had also tried onBeforeinput approach for getting the input from android keyboard but it is not working in all scenarios.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.